# Using find fact in CLIPS

Tags: clips, expert-system

I have a fact

```
(is-started TRUE)
```

I want to find if the fact exists with

```
(any-factp ((?is (is-started TRUE))) TRUE)
```

but this gives me Missing function declaration for is-started.

How can i determine if this fact exists with any-factp?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fields of an implied deftemplate fact can be accessed using the implicitly defined multifield slot named implied:

```
CLIPS> (assert (is-started TRUE))
<Fact-1>
CLIPS> (any-factp ((?f is-started)) TRUE)
TRUE
CLIPS> (any-factp ((?f is-started)) (eq ?f:implied (create$ TRUE)))
TRUE
CLIPS> (any-factp ((?f is-started)) (eq ?f:implied (create$)))
FALSE
CLIPS>
```

Comment: thanks for your examples, it's not so clear in the documentation